# Map Database exception to Http status code

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, exception, http-status-codes

When I try to delete an entity in my database I get a ForeignKey Constraint Exception.

I expect that exception, handle it on the server but also want to handle it on the client.

What status code should I use to say: You can not delete this entity and prevent on the client side the deletion of the entity in the UI.

Comment: Something in the 4xx range.  My suggestion would be `>= 470`.

Comment: >= 470 does not exist in 4xx range...

Comment: Well if you want to be pedantic about it.... `>= 470 < 500`

Comment: What I wanted to say is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes There is no 470 status code or higher in 4xx range.

Comment: That is a list of status codes that have either w3c definitions, or industry accepted definitions.  You don't wasn't to have your custom code conflicting with a "defined" code - that would lead to insanity!  Choose a code that doesn't have an existing definition.

Comment: aaahhh. you mean a custom http code just for my purpose? Ok understand.

Comment: Good.  Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Would you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one real "exception" code - 500.

For some operations code from [4xx range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) may be suitable. Maybe "403-forbidden" wold be ok for this case.

If you need to have more comprehensive client side handling - send 200 with response including error information with empty value instead of result.

Comment: Hey Alexei, This exception is valid. I expect it. This can not be 500.